# Multi Class and Multi Label Simple Model

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I have been working for a few weeks to complete a project. The project seems simple , but there's a lot of moving parts. So 
- Create a simple CNN model that has 4 input images. The images are of trees. Images are the trunk of a tree, branches , leafs and the roots of the tree.
- There are 8 different trees. 
- The goal feed the model the four images and have the model detect which tree it is.
- I must Create the raw data from google images (search)
As I work through this problem for a school project , I am struggling on how to pre-process the images for the hot-label and multi class. Then insure my model architecture is accurate.

```html
# import the necessary packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dropout
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense , LSTM, concatenate, Input, Flatten

# define four inputs ( Different photos of trees)
inputA = Input(shape=(308, 308, 1)) # Trunk 
inputB = Input(shape=(308, 308, 1)) # Branch
inputC = Input(shape=(308, 308, 1)) # Leafs
inputD = Input(shape=(308, 308, 1)) # Roots
 
# the first branch operates on the first input
a = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(inputA)
a = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(a)
a = Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=a)
 
# the second branch opreates on the second input
b = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(inputB)
b = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(b)
b = Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=b)

# the third branch opreates on the third input
c = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(inputC)
c = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(c)
c = Model(inputs=inputC, outputs=c)

# the fourth branch opreates on the fourth input
d = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(inputD)
d = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(d)
d = Model(inputs=inputD, outputs=d)
 
# combine the output of the four branches
combined = concatenate([a.output, b.output, c.output, d.output])
 
# apply a FC layer and then a regression prediction on the
# combined outputs
z = Dense(128, activation="relu")(combined)
z = Dense(4, activation="softmax")(z)
 
# our model will accept the inputs of the four branches and then output a single value
model = Model(inputs=[a.input, b.input, c.input, d.input], outputs=z)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is how I have been trying to hot-label for pre-processing data.

```html
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

train_data = ""
test_data = ""

def one_hot_label(img):
 label = img.split(".")[0]
 if label == "Trunk";
  ohl = np.array([1,0,0,0])
 elif label == "Branch":
  ohl = np.array([0,1,0,0])
  elif label == "Leaf":
  ohl = np.array([0,0,1,0])
  elif label == "Root":
  ohl = np.array([0,0,0,1])  
 return ohl
def train_data_with_label();
 train_images = []
 for i in tqdm(os.listdir(train_data)):
  path = os.path.join(train_data, i)
  img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  img = cv2.resize(img, (308, 308))
  train_images.append([np.array(img), one_hot_label(i)])
 shuffle(train_images)
 return train_images

def test_data_with_label();
 test_images = []
 for i in tqdm(os.listdir(test_data)):
  path = os.path.join(test_data, i)
  img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  img = cv2.resize(img, (308, 308))
  test_images.append([np.array(img), one_hot_label(i)])
 shuffle(test_images)
 return test_images
```

This is a huge post. I know I am a mess and really struggling. When you run the data its accuracy is so low , I know something is wrong. (around 18%) 
If anyone can help !! pleaseeee . It doesnt have to be the exact answer even a direction is helpful.
I am grateful for this site and the people on it.

Thanks
Noob Coder Dyl

Comment: on thing i noticed is, u didnt normalize the images. either using mean-std normalization or min-max normalization